# How to use datepicker when page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a jquery function that use `load` and `preventDefault`. Below are the codes from my `main.php` page,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ajaxLoad(e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(page, function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });      
  $(document).on("click", "a#staff_insert, ajaxLoad);
});
</script>
```

On the page that I load that is `staff-add.php`, i have a form with the date input using the datepicker,

```
<input type="text" name="calendar" id="datepicker">
```

May I know how to make the datepicker function available because when i click on the `input` field, the calendar won't appear. Do I have to insert the datepicker function on `staff-add.php` as well like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Help is appreciated.

> Update with new codes.
>   Just to inform that I managed to get it done but now the problem is,
>
> when I clicked on different link, and click back to page that has the
>   datepicker, the datepicker will not appear. It will only appear if I
>   did not go to other link. May I know what am I doing wrong?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ajaxLoad(e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'staff_insert'){
      var page = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#content').load(page+ ' #calendar', function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      }); 
    } else {
       var page = $(this).attr('href');
       $('#content').load(page);
    }  
}
$(document).on("click", "a#staff_info, a#staff_insert", ajaxLoad);
});
</script>
```

if I see on my browser, the error was `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`

> **Update - Resolved**

I'm able to resolved it by inserting `var j = jQuery.noConflict();` on the codes. May someone explain why do I need that? Still searching for the reason. Thanks

Comment: You sure you do not multiple #datepicker elements?

Comment: My bet (besides the comment from @void) would be that you have to reinitialize datepicker after AJAX call.

Comment: document ready function fires only once....if you loading html via ajax it will not fire document ready function again...

Comment: Is there any other way or the best method to do it?

Comment: are you sure you included jquery ui file ?

Comment: Are you working on a local file system project?

Comment: do you mean the .css file? I included on the top. Is it this file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

Comment: the file is on my PC and once it is complete, we will use it for office use only

Comment: Try to set the protocol like http, as the jQuery include

Comment: do you mean for the jquery-ui.js? do you have an example or maybe a reference I can check. Sorry @IrvinDominin, actually I'm new to jQuery

Comment: @Amran look at the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing locally I think you are working with file protocol (like file://).

Currently you are referencing your script/css include without protocol:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

in this case is used the relative URI, basically it allows the browser to determine whether to use http:// or https:// based on the protocol that your page is using.

You are using file protocol so the page try to load:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="file://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and it will not work, so set the protocol like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried to change the protocol but it still give the same error